# How to change the SHA1 Fingerprint in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: 46:E8:47:33:68:00:86:A7:E9:EE:59:9C:8A:F1:57:EC:EB:D2:A4:6E
but the certificate used to sign the app bundle that you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: 02:4C:6B:C4:8D:F4:85:61:EF:33:87:AB:71:10:B2:F2:20:69:A1:4B

I COMPRESS MY FLUTTER PROJECT AND THE I EXTRACT AND RE UPLOAD BUT IT DOESINT WORK BUT THE KEY HAS NO CHANGE SAME KEY IS USED BUT I CANT UPLOAD THIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so I faced similar issue when I needed to upload a new update for the app but because the build was from different app it can't be installed on the device, if this is the case with you then the reason is actually two devices have different keystore which makes one app different from other one

You can follow the guide below
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#zippy=

Hoping this help!